# Problem with \subfigure

Tags: subfloats

I am having some troubles in using `\subfigure`  in LaTeX.

Here's my code:

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering
  \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{./figure/bos_onto6.png}\label{fig:SGD_1_single}}
  \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width =0.32\textwidth]{./figure/bos_onto7.png}\label{fig:SGD_2_single}}
  \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width =0.32\textwidth]{./figure/bos_onto8.png}\label{fig:SGD_3_single}}
  \caption{False negative (FN) rate vs. false positive (FP) rate obtained by varying the threshold $\tau$ in predicting
  the GO annotations of \emph{Saccharomyces cerevisiae} (SGD) genes. a) BP: Biological Process, b) MF: Molecular Function, c) CC: Cellular Component GO ontologies.}\label{fig:SGD_single}
\end{figure*}
```

And here there's the problem that compiler gives to me:

```
[4]
Overfull \hbox (5.7111pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 689--713
 [][] 
! Argument of \Gin@iii has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.750 ...e/bos_onto6.png}\label{fig:SGD_1_single}}

?
```

Any help?

Here's my 2nd minimal NOT working example: it comes from my original file

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
% Add the compsoc option for Computer Society conferences.
%
% If IEEEtran.cls has not been installed into the LaTeX system files,
% manually specify the path to it like:
% \documentclass[conference]{../sty/IEEEtran}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,latexsym,amssymb,euscript,xr}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
% \usepackage{graphicx} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files

\def\blu{\color{blue}}
\def\nero{\color{black}}

% 3 Tabelle
% - aree e tempi
% - risultati validazione quantitativa iea e temporali
% - descrizione tabelle iniziali (righe gialle e blu)

% 2 figure ognuna da 3 sottofigure

% Some very useful LaTeX packages include:
% (uncomment the ones you want to load)


% *** MISC UTILITY PACKAGES ***
%
\usepackage{ifpdf}
% Heiko Oberdiek's ifpdf.sty is very useful if you need conditional
% compilation based on whether the output is pdf or dvi.
% usage:
% \ifpdf
%   % pdf code
% \else
%   % dvi code
% \fi
% The latest version of ifpdf.sty can be obtained from:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/
% Also, note that IEEEtran.cls V1.7 and later provides a builtin
% \ifCLASSINFOpdf conditional that works the same way.
% When switching from latex to pdflatex and vice-versa, the compiler may
% have to be run twice to clear warning/error messages.



\def\x{{\mathbf x}}
\def\A{{\mathbf A}}
\def\a{{\mathbf a}}
\def\ah{{\hat{\mathbf a}}}
\def\e{{\mathbf e}}
\def\u{{\mathbf u}}
\def\At{{\tilde{\mathbf A}}}
\def\Ah{{\hat{\mathbf A}}}
\def\U{{\mathbf U}}
\def\Uh{{\hat{\mathbf U}}}
\def\Vh{{\hat{\mathbf V}}}
\def\V{{\mathbf V}}
\def\V{{\mathbf V}}
\def\S{{\mathbf S}}
\def\Si{{\mathbf \Sigma}}
\def\Sih{\hat{{\mathbf \Sigma}}}
\def\I{{\mathbf I}}
\def\T{{\mathbf T}}
\def\G{{\mathbf G}}
\def\S{{\mathbf S}}
\def\Q{{\mathbf Q}}
\def\W{{\mathbf W}}
\def\one{{\mathbf 1}}
\def\blu{\color{blue}}
\def\rosso{\color{red}}
\def\nero{\color{black}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}


% *** CITATION PACKAGES ***
%
%\usepackage{cite}
% cite.sty was written by Donald Arseneau
% V1.6 and later of IEEEtran pre-defines the format of the cite.sty package
% \cite{} output to follow that of IEEE. Loading the cite package will
% result in citation numbers being automatically sorted and properly
% "compressed/ranged". e.g., [1], [9], [2], [7], [5], [6] without using
% cite.sty will become [1], [2], [5]--[7], [9] using cite.sty. cite.sty's
% \cite will automatically add leading space, if needed. Use cite.sty's
% noadjust option (cite.sty V3.8 and later) if you want to turn this off.
% cite.sty is already installed on most LaTeX systems. Be sure and use
% version 4.0 (2003-05-27) and later if using hyperref.sty. cite.sty does
% not currently provide for hyperlinked citations.
% The latest version can be obtained at:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cite/
% The documentation is contained in the cite.sty file itself.






% *** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***
%
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics 
  %\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\else
  % or other class option (dvipsone, dvipdf, if not using dvips). graphicx
  % will default to the driver specified in the system graphics.cfg if no
  % driver is specified.
   \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../eps/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi
% graphicx was written by David Carlisle and Sebastian Rahtz. It is
% required if you want graphics, photos, etc. graphicx.sty is already
% installed on most LaTeX systems. The latest version and documentation can
% be obtained at:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/graphics/
% Another good source of documentation is "Using Imported Graphics in
% LaTeX2e" by Keith Reckdahl which can be found as epslatex.ps or
% epslatex.pdf at: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/
%
% latex, and pdflatex in dvi mode, support graphics in encapsulated
% postscript (.eps) format. pdflatex in pdf mode supports graphics
% in .pdf, .jpeg, .png and .mps (metapost) formats. Users should ensure
% that all non-photo figures use a vector format (.eps, .pdf, .mps) and
% not a bitmapped formats (.jpeg, .png). IEEE frowns on bitmapped formats
% which can result in "jaggedy"/blurry rendering of lines and letters as
% well as large increases in file sizes.
%
% You can find documentation about the pdfTeX application at:
% http://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex





% *** MATH PACKAGES ***
%
%\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
% A popular package from the American Mathematical Society that provides
% many useful and powerful commands for dealing with mathematics. If using
% it, be sure to load this package with the cmex10 option to ensure that
% only type 1 fonts will utilized at all point sizes. Without this option,
% it is possible that some math symbols, particularly those within
% footnotes, will be rendered in bitmap form which will result in a
% document that can not be IEEE Xplore compliant!
%
% Also, note that the amsmath package sets \interdisplaylinepenalty to 10000
% thus preventing page breaks from occurring within multiline equations. Use:
%\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
% after loading amsmath to restore such page breaks as IEEEtran.cls normally
% does. amsmath.sty is already installed on most LaTeX systems. The latest
% version and documentation can be obtained at:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/





% *** SPECIALIZED LIST PACKAGES ***
%
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
% algorithmic.sty was written by Peter Williams and Rogerio Brito.
% This package provides an algorithmic environment fo describing algorithms.
% You can use the algorithmic environment in-text or within a figure
% environment to provide for a floating algorithm. Do NOT use the algorithm
% floating environment provided by algorithm.sty (by the same authors) or
% algorithm2e.sty (by Christophe Fiorio) as IEEE does not use dedicated
% algorithm float types and packages that provide these will not provide
% correct IEEE style captions. The latest version and documentation of
% algorithmic.sty can be obtained at:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/
% There is also a support site at:
% http://algorithms.berlios.de/index.html
% Also of interest may be the (relatively newer and more customizable)
% algorithmicx.sty package by Szasz Janos:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/




% *** ALIGNMENT PACKAGES ***
%
%\usepackage{array}
% Frank Mittelbach's and David Carlisle's array.sty patches and improves
% the standard LaTeX2e array and tabular environments to provide better
% appearance and additional user controls. As the default LaTeX2e table
% generation code is lacking to the point of almost being broken with
% respect to the quality of the end results, all users are strongly
% advised to use an enhanced (at the very least that provided by array.sty)
% set of table tools. array.sty is already installed on most systems. The
% latest version and documentation can be obtained at:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/


\usepackage{mdwmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
% Also highly recommended is Mark Wooding's extremely powerful MDW tools,
% especially mdwmath.sty and mdwtab.sty which are used to format equations
% and tables, respectively. The MDWtools set is already installed on most
% LaTeX systems. The lastest version and documentation is available at:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdwtools/


% IEEEtran contains the IEEEeqnarray family of commands that can be used to
% generate multiline equations as well as matrices, tables, etc., of high
% quality.


%\usepackage{eqparbox}
% Also of notable interest is Scott Pakin's eqparbox package for creating
% (automatically sized) equal width boxes - aka "natural width parboxes".
% Available at:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/eqparbox/





% *** SUBFIGURE PACKAGES ***
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
% subfigure.sty was written by Steven Douglas Cochran. This package makes it
% easy to put subfigures in your figures. e.g., "Figure 1a and 1b". For IEEE
% work, it is a good idea to load it with the tight package option to reduce
% the amount of white space around the subfigures. subfigure.sty is already
% installed on most LaTeX systems. The latest version and documentation can
% be obtained at:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/subfigure/
% subfigure.sty has been superceeded by subfig.sty.



%\usepackage[caption=false]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subfig}
% subfig.sty, also written by Steven Douglas Cochran, is the modern
% replacement for subfigure.sty. However, subfig.sty requires and
% automatically loads Axel Sommerfeldt's caption.sty which will override
% IEEEtran.cls handling of captions and this will result in nonIEEE style
% figure/table captions. To prevent this problem, be sure and preload
% caption.sty with its "caption=false" package option. This is will preserve
% IEEEtran.cls handing of captions. Version 1.3 (2005/06/28) and later
% (recommended due to many improvements over 1.2) of subfig.sty supports
% the caption=false option directly:
%\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
%
% The latest version and documentation can be obtained at:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/
% The latest version and documentation of caption.sty can be obtained at:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/




% *** FLOAT PACKAGES ***
%
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
% fixltx2e, the successor to the earlier fix2col.sty, was written by
% Frank Mittelbach and David Carlisle. This package corrects a few problems
% in the LaTeX2e kernel, the most notable of which is that in current
% LaTeX2e releases, the ordering of single and double column floats is not
% guaranteed to be preserved. Thus, an unpatched LaTeX2e can allow a
% single column figure to be placed prior to an earlier double column
% figure. The latest version and documentation can be found at:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/



\usepackage{stfloats}
% stfloats.sty was written by Sigitas Tolusis. This package gives LaTeX2e
% the ability to do double column floats at the bottom of the page as well
% as the top. (e.g., "\begin{figure*}[!b]" is not normally possible in
% LaTeX2e). It also provides a command:
%\fnbelowfloat
% to enable the placement of footnotes below bottom floats (the standard
% LaTeX2e kernel puts them above bottom floats). This is an invasive package
% which rewrites many portions of the LaTeX2e float routines. It may not work
% with other packages that modify the LaTeX2e float routines. The latest
% version and documentation can be obtained at:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/sttools/
% Documentation is contained in the stfloats.sty comments as well as in the
% presfull.pdf file. Do not use the stfloats baselinefloat ability as IEEE
% does not allow \baselineskip to stretch. Authors submitting work to the
% IEEE should note that IEEE rarely uses double column equations and
% that authors should try to avoid such use. Do not be tempted to use the
% cuted.sty or midfloat.sty packages (also by Sigitas Tolusis) as IEEE does
% not format its papers in such ways.





% *** PDF, URL AND HYPERLINK PACKAGES ***
%
%\usepackage{url}
% url.sty was written by Donald Arseneau. It provides better support for
% handling and breaking URLs. url.sty is already installed on most LaTeX
% systems. The latest version can be obtained at:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/misc/
% Read the url.sty source comments for usage information. Basically,
% \url{my_url_here}.





% *** Do not adjust lengths that control margins, column widths, etc. ***
% *** Do not use packages that alter fonts (such as pslatex).         ***
% There should be no need to do such things with IEEEtran.cls V1.6 and later.
% (Unless specifically asked to do so by the journal or conference you plan
% to submit to, of course. )


% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}


\begin{document}

\title{Minimal NOT working example}


% author names and affiliations
% use a multiple column layout for up to three different
% affiliations
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Peter Griffin}
\IEEEauthorblockA{University of Quahog}}
\maketitle


\section{Conclusions}\label{conclusion}
\label{conclusion} The conclusion goes here.

 \begin{figure*}[t]
 \centering
   \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{./figure/bos_onto6.png}\label{fig:SGD_1_single}}
   \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width =0.32\textwidth]{./figure/bos_onto7.png}\label{fig:SGD_2_single}}
   \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width =0.32\textwidth]{./figure/bos_onto8.png}\label{fig:SGD_3_single}}
\caption{False negative (FN) rate vs. false positive (FP) rate obtained by varying the threshold $\tau$ in predicting
   the GO annotations of \emph{Saccharomyces cerevisiae} (SGD) genes. a) BP: Biological Process, b) MF: Molecular Function, c) CC: Cellular Component GO ontologies.}\label{fig:SGD_single}
 \end{figure*}







% that's all folks
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem, not just code-snippets.

Comment: It looks to me that you are loading the older `graphics` package, not the modern `graphicx` package. Both provide `\includegraphics` but the `key=value` syntax is only provided by the latter (which loads the former by itself anyway).

Comment: Thanx but problem persists with graphicx : <./figure/bos_onto6.png, id=28, 642.4pt x 401.5pt>
<use ./figure/bos_onto6.png>
! Undefined control sequence.
\sf@@sub@label #1->\@bsphack \sf@oldlabel 
                                          {#1}\ifhyperrefloaded \begingroup ...
l.750 ...e/bos_onto6.png}\label{fig:SGD_1_single}}

Comment: You need to post a full minimal example, otherwise it will not be possible to really help you. See the above mentioned link if you need help.

Comment: By adding `\usepackage{subfigure}` and `\usepackage{graphicx}` (1) to your "minimal" example I no longer get any errors (1: I used the `demo` option, because I don't have your images of course).

Comment: `subfigure` is obsolete. Don't load it and use `subfig`. It's just a matter of changing `\subfigure` into `\subfloat` in the document. Or, if you don't want to do it, just say `\newcommand{\subfigure}{\subfloat}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I now minimized your code to get a real [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) by removing all unrelated material. It then looks like you load both the `subfigure` and the `subfig` packages, which both try to do the same thing and apparently collide. After removing `subfig` it works, but with it get the same error you got.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% remove the 'demo' option in the real document
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
%\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subfig}

\begin{document}

 \begin{figure*}
     \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{./figure/bos_onto6.png}\label{fig:SGD_1_single}}
 \end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

---

#### Old:

By looking at `\Gin@iii` I figured out that the error is caused because the old `\includegraphics[a,b][c,d]{filename}` syntax is used.
You seem to load the older `graphics` package but not the modern `graphicx` package (note the `s` vs. `x`). Both provide `\includegraphics` but the `key=value` syntax is only provided by the latter (which loads the former by itself anyway).
Simply add `\usepackage{graphicx}` into your preamble should fix this.

(You might also want to remove the space between the `width` and `=` in two of your `\includegraphics`.)

Comment: I've added a new "minimal workin' example", could you try to run it on your pc's? Thanx

Comment: Thanx Martin, but unfortunately, by removing subfig package, it still does not work to me... here's the new error: ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@endfloatbox ...pagefalse \outer@nobreak \egroup 
                                                  \color@endbox 
l.349  \end{figure*}

Comment: @DavideChicco.it: Mmm, the issue seems to be caused by the `fixltx2e` package. If you remove it the error disappears. You don't need this package at any cost anyway.

Comment: @DavideChicco.it: Glad I could help. Please try to post real MWE next time by yourself. If you click the check-mark at the upper left you can accept this answer officially and conclude the question with it. Thanks.